# R grouping time index_by(). index_by() fails to work on object types 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame', 'mts', 'ts'

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, tibble

** **Problem** **

Having challenge to code to dataset that is part of tsibbledata, vic_elec. The
Function index_by(), library tsibble, is not recognizing any data formats for function invocation. I have tried in vain both my Windows environment and a separate computer using RCloud, as with the same error.

The method, index_by() has failed to work on any object type, e.g, 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame', 'mts', 'ts'. Have tried for hours even days, had inconsistent outcomes in trying to read dataset with index_by(). I was able to independently apply summarize() when removing index_by() function. Ask other but no one has been able to solve error issue with index_by() on so many object formats.

** **Index_by() function [tbl_ts] format** **

Effort using tsibbledata supplied format [ tbl_ts [52,608 x 5] (S3: tbl_ts/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame) ]

No method applied to object class 'tbl', 'tbe_df', 'data.frame'

[image: index_by(Date) Error]

** **Index_by() function tibble format** **

Effort using cast to tibble, eg., as_tibble(vic_elec), tibble format [tbl_df [52,608 x 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame) ]

No method applied to object class 'tbl', 'tbe_df', 'data.frame'

[image: Index_by(Date)]

** **Data view** for dataset: 'vic_elec' **

[image: Data view]

** **Environment** **

Windows,  RStudio version 1.1.456 – © 2009-2018 RStudio, Inc.
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio Safari/538.1 Qt/5.6.2

RCloud

Answer (score 0):

The problem and issue was due to function name overriding. I had a library loaded early in the list of libraries, then following, a later on the queue for loading next libraries, one of the functions apparently overrode the early queue loaded library. When I reversed a few key libraries, and  minimizing some libraries that were not needed in early in the program, this reversal of libraries then did not override the functions, and the code problem issue was solved.